# Navigation Drawer Fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation, fragment, navigation-drawer

I'm using a navigation drawer in my android app, but I noticed that for the functionality of my app the navigation drawer should change its options in relation with the content of the fragment. So I want to change the navigation drawer items. If I use the navigation drawer in a fragment and I load it in onCreate of my Main Activity, can I change the navigation drawer same as a normal fragment? Change the fragment is the best way to realize what I want?

I've found many example of the use of Navigation Drawer but the items are always the same for the entire app.

MainActivity - onCreate

```
drawerFragment = (FragmentDrawer) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer);
drawerFragment.setUp(R.id.fragment_navigation_drawer, (DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout), mToolbar);
drawerFragment.setDrawerListener(this);
```

How I change a fragment after an item in navigation drawer has been selected

```
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();
```

Comment: do you want this: suppose in your app you have a navigation drawer  with four fragments now you want to change your fragment when someone click on navigation ... am i right?

Comment: no, I already implements this. I would that every time I change fragment, every fragment has its custom items in navigation drawer. For example, there are 4 different fragment and 4 different navigation drawer, 1 for each one.

Comment: what do you mean by this "  items are always the same for the entire app "

Comment: In the link below every time I open the navigation drawer the list of items is always the same for every fragment I've opened. I would that if I'm in Friends my navigation show for e.g Google / Facebook, if I'm in Messages my navigation drawer show Twitter / Gmail and not always Home/Friends/Messages.  (if you are seeing the link you understand what I mean)

http://www.androidhive.info/2015/04/android-getting-started-with-material-design/

Comment: may be your fragmentTransaction.replace(....) is same for every nv item click... or you have loaded same thing in every individual fragment . do you please post  more code for fragment transaction..and fragment onCreateView  method..

Comment: stupid question! I'm sorry. I use for every fragment an XML layout with a static drawer layout. Thank you for your time

Comment: hmm great... at least you find out it.... welcome